# How to search Azure Devops Code Repos w/ Powershell using Devops REST API and output to CSV

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops

How do you search Azure Devops Code Repos w/ Powershell using Devops REST API and output to CSV.

Comment: I tested your script, it works well. Do you encounter any problems?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, what do you want to ask through this ticket? It seems the script you gave is the answer to the title.

Comment: Yeah... should I post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm new to this, I just wanted to share the solution.  Is there a different way to do this?  For instance.  Post Question and then answer seperately?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily.

Comment: Edited original Question and posted solution as Answer and Marked as you suggested.  Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution for this but found enough inspiration around the internet to put this together from this article written by [Tenbulls](https://tenbulls.co.uk/2020/03/11/querying-azure-devops-rest-api-with-powershell/)

MS Documentation on this subject can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/code%20search%20results/fetch%20code%20search%20results?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Instead of exhaustively going through the step by step process of putting this together, I just want to highlight the important hurdles that I overcame.

1. When the documentation says to use almsearch.dev.azure.com, that's what it means. Don't do what I did and think, oh that's probably incorrect and use dev.azure.com.
2. Giving your PAT (personal access token) the appropriate amount of rights is important. I, out of laziness and a propensity for anarchy chose to give my token full access after failing to give it the right amount of read access.

Here's the entire script in all of it's glory.

```
    #set your desired org, search and PAT variables
$orgname = "YourOrgName"
$textsearch = 'YourTextString'
$personalToken = "YourPersonalAccessTokenGeneratedInDevOps"

#set your desired file and path properties
$folderpath = "C:\OutBound\"
$file = "OutputSearchResults.csv"
$FileName = $folderpath + $file

#force create directory
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $folderpath

#initial test to remove csv file if it already exists
if (Test-Path $FileName) {
    Remove-Item $FileName
  }
  
#converting textsearch to json format for later use
$body = 
@{
  searchText = $textsearch
  '$top' =  300
}
$json = $body | ConvertTo-Json
 
#Setting token and header for Get and Post requests
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

#outer query getting a list of all projects in the azure devops organization
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/" + $orgname + "/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1"
$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
$output.value | ForEach-Object {
    
    #inner query that searches repositories for the string entered in $textsearch
    #-Body $json is the where the magic happens.  Many additional request properties to choose from in MS documentation
    $project = $_.name
    $urlsearch = "https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/" + $orgname + "/" + $project + "/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=6.1-preview.1"    
    $output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlsearch -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Body $json

    $output.results |Export-Csv -Path $FileName -Append
}
```